# search html table generated with d3.csv function in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to have a simple search functionality on the table that is generated with d3.csv function in d3.js.

This is my script that is rendering the html table, when d3.csv has been passed to it:

```
<script>
    function tabulate(data, columns) {
        var table = d3.select("#table").append("table"),
        caption = table.append("caption");
        caption.append("caption").append("table").text("XYZ")
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

        thead.append("tr")
            .selectAll("th")
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
            .append("th")
                .text(function(column) { return column; });

        d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;
                var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("tr")
                tr.each(function(d) {
                var self = d3.select(this);
                self.append("td")
                .html(d["A1"]);

        if (d.A2 == "SUCCESS")
            {
            self.append("td")
            .style("background-color", '#66cc00')
            .append("a")
            .text(d.A2);
            }
        else {
            self.append("td")
            .style("background-color", '#ff3333')
            .append("a")
            .text(d.A2);
            }

        });
    });
    return table;
    }
    var Table = tabulate(d3.csv, ["H1", "H2"],);
</script>
```

What I need now is to have a simple search on this table as per this: http://jsfiddle.net/gnx917r8/

I am not able to link this table entries into the search function.

Please help.

Comment: you don't use the **passed** d3.csv. What a strange way of setting the background color. You don't there exist something like CSS? In the fiddle you don't use d3 at all.

Comment: Well, the fiddle in my question is a sample one that I am referring to for the type of search I want to apply in the code I shared. It is not developed by me.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Was missing reference to jquery...my bad:(